# Libgdx Scene2d pack actor size

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

[image: the button component]

I have a table that I add buttons that I'm extending (to which I add labels in the constructor) and as you can see in the debug view (the bottom red line in the attached picture) I wish for the button to be sized according to the components within it (minimum size).
I'm sure there's a simple way to do that in scene2d but I cant seem to find it..

Comment: It seems as I read trough Button class that the height currently is the prefHeight which in this case is the the TextureRegionDrawable image height (image is 320 pixels high and the button wont allow to resize the button below that value) is there any method or way to bypass that besides overriding methods?

Comment: I dont have access to fully override the method it seems that a 9patch will be the easiest workaround in this situation in this situation...